# Count referral and calculate price from product table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I am creating referral system. Now I have two table one users and second is product.
In User Table I Have two column one is user Id one is referred_by.
Here is my table.

```
+----+-------------+
| id | referred_by |
+----+-------------+
| 35 | 0           |
| 36 | 35          |
| 40 | 35          |
| 41 | 35          |
| 44 | 41          |
| 45 | 36          |
| 46 | 41          |
+----+-------------+
```

Here is query. This query count number of referrals

```
select referred_by, count(*) from users group by referred_by.
```

But can I modify result like User ID 35 Have 3 Referral 40,41,and 46.

Now I have product table And user Id is in Product table.

```
+----+---------+---------------+
| id | user_id | product_price |
+----+---------+---------------+
|  1 |      37 |           300 |
|  2 |      38 |           300 |
|  3 |      40 |           300 |
|  4 |      41 |           300 |
|  5 |      42 |           300 |
|  6 |      44 |           300 |
|  7 |      45 |           300 |
|  8 |      35 |           300 |
|  9 |      35 |           300 |
| 10 |      35 |           300 |
| 11 |      35 |           300 |
| 12 |      46 |           300 |
+----+---------+---------------+
```

My INner Join  query Here.

```
select users.id,users.referred_by
,orders_products.user_id,orders_products.product_price 
from users 
inner join  orders_products  on  users.id=orders_products.user_id;
```

And output of this.

```
| id | referred_by | user_id | product_price |
+----+-------------+---------+---------------+
| 40 | 35          |      40 |           300 |
| 41 | 35          |      41 |           300 |
| 44 | 41          |      44 |           300 |
| 45 | 36          |      45 |           300 |
| 35 | 0           |      35 |           300 |
| 35 | 0           |      35 |           300 |
| 35 | 0           |      35 |           300 |
| 35 | 0           |      35 |           300 |
| 46 | 41          |      46 |           300 |
+----+-------------+---------+---------------+
```

Now. What I am trying to do.
if user Id 35 Have 3 referrals 36,40 and 41 then calculate the sum of  price of 35 ,36,40 and 41.
Means .
Please she my next level try @I am using this query .

```
select users.id,users.referred_by
,orders_products.user_id,sum(orders_products.product_price)
 from users 
inner join  orders_products  on  users.id=orders_products.user_id group by user_id;



+----+-------------+---------+------------------------------------+
| id | referred_by | user_id | sum(orders_products.product_price) |
+----+-------------+---------+------------------------------------+
| 35 | 0           |      35 |                               1200 |
| 40 | 35          |      40 |                                300 |
| 41 | 35          |      41 |                                300 |
| 44 | 41          |      44 |                                300 |
| 45 | 36          |      45 |                                300 |
| 46 | 41          |      46 |                                300 |
+----+-------------+---------+------------------------------------+
```

Now How can I get Desire Out Put From This result.
I am Trying to get Out put like this.

```
User_id ,referrals, total price
35,      3(36,40,42)        ,  20000(this will be total price of user 35,36,40,41)
```

Comment: I don't get it.  Can you include the expected output from your second input table?

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen@pleae Let me know How can easly I descibe to you.?

Comment: @web Once check my answer.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen@you there?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: hims056@I am using 5.6

Comment: @web: Check the answer now. BTY use `@` *before* username to notify them like I did.